# Convolution along singleton dimensions on GPU in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am trying to implement a convolution along one dimension of a large N-D array in parallel in Matlab. The convolution filter is small enough that it doesn't make sense to use an FFT to do it. For very long 1D signals, I know I can call `conv(gpuArrayA,gpuArrayB)`, and for many functions I can use `bsxfun` to apply a function in parallel across a single dimension of a gpuArray, however when I try

`bsxfun(@conv,gpuArrayA,gpuArrayB)`

I get the error

```
Error using gpuArray/bsxfun
Use of 'conv' is not supported.
```

So then is there a way to implement this in Matlab without having to write custom CUDA code?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just call convn() with a 1D convolution kernel, e.g.,

```
 A=gpuArray(rand(100,100,100));
 kernel=gpuArray([1;1;1]);

 result = convn(A,kernel,'same');  % convolution along dim=1
```

I find I get faster results with this than an equivalent CPU version, so there must be some GPU parallelization built into this.